# Knowing which codecs to install to play a video properly

Tags: audio, video, codec

I donwloaded a video in mp4 format from YouTube using downloadhelper firefox plugin. When I play the video with Wondershare, it plays but there is no audio. How do I know which audio codec I need to download in order to play the video properly

Comment: MediaInfo is a great tool to see info about your files.

Comment: This isn't a direct solution, but an alternative. I would suggest VLC (It supports a ton of codecs). http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html